# Read a file in clientside, javascript, java applets

Tags: javascript, applet

I'm trying to write a web-based application where a JavaScript has to read a file from the client's computer and upload the data to a file in the server.

It was when I was going through the net that I found that JavaScript is not able to do this.

I found [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reading2.htm) site but I cannot understand any of it. Looks as if incomplete to me. Maybe because I'm just a starter.

Can somebody give me some help here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That site uses Java to read files *on the server*. You'd have to trigger a **File Open** dialog via the Applet and then send that to the JavaScript.

Comment: When you say, "where a JavaScript has to read a file", do you mean a simple file upload from the client to the server or do you mean something else?

Comment: Here's the real problem:   I got a C program that writes to a file in an infinite loop. What I got to do is to read the content of this file and write the same data to a file in the server. I have to read the file time to time and write the newly added data to the file in server. File Open dialogs are not much of a use in this kind of situation I guess. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Is it really necessary to have this function in a web-page? A simple local script seems much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the HTML5 FileSystem API ?

A good wrapper around it has been released recently "filer.js"

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/14866798359/introducing-filer-js